# Programatically determine highest video quality from filename

Tags: php

So let's say we have the following 3 filenames:

```
[HorribleSubs] Sora no Method - 12 [480p].mkv.torrent
[HorribleSubs] Sora no Method - 12 [720p].mkv.torrent
[HorribleSubs] Sora no Method - 12 [1080p].mkv.torrent
```

What would be an efficient way of determining which filename is the highest quality, assuming that 1080p is the highest quality.

So in case `720p` is the highest resolution, I want that file to be selected. Or if there is a file with a higher resolution (2.7k), I want that file to be selected.

In other words, I need a way to match the file to any of those 3 resolutions (for now) and determine which filename has the highest resolution

Comment: are you just looking for files names with "1080p" in it ?

Comment: no, in that case I could just use `stristr()`. I'm looking for the file with the highest resolution. So if it's only up to 720p, I want that one. If it's only up to 480p I want that one.

Comment: Use a regex to find the resolution, something like `\[\d+p\]`.

Comment: then compare against an array of resolutions listed in order - perhaps

Comment: yep that's what I ended up doing!